# Model trouble in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have 
customer.rb

```
    class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_authentic
    has_many :credit_cards
    has_many :telephones
    has_many :virtual_pays
end
```

telephone.rb

```
    class Telephone < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customers
end
```

When I use rails console ad write Customer.all, i'll get all data from db table customers, but when i try to fetch all data include cutomer telephone i get error 
I write: customers.telephones.all, then i try Customer.Telephone.all, but how to correctly do this?

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `customers' for
>   main:Object
>           from (irb):6
>           from /home/pp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in`
>   start'
>           from /home/pp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in
>   `start'
>           from /home/pp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in`
>   '
>           from script/rails:6:in `require'
>           from script/rails:6:in`'

Also I correct write model?

Comment: You want to know how to query the customers telephone numbers?

Answer (score 1):

In your Telephone model, it should be belongs_to :customer (singular).

Comment: and how to write than in console?

Comment: @pavel You would write that in your model, not the console. In your model, you would change belongs_to :customers to belongs_to :customer. Then load the console and try your customer calls.

Comment: )) I know, I ask what I should write in console? customer.telephones? when so, it doesnt work

Comment: sorry. that was not clear from your comment. since it's a one-to-many relationship (Customers have many telephones), I would use 
customers = Customer.all (or to keep it simpler, I would do: customer = Customers.first so I just got one customer back to test).

Then, in the console you'd do either: customers[0].telephones or customer.telephones (depending on what you initially typed in the console). Hope that helps.